# VS 2012 Open Design and Code on separate tab

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I open HTML file on VS2012, I have the option to view code/split/design.

Is it possible to open design and code on the separate tab/window ? I want to have a better view of the design when I edit the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does split view not enough? Did you tried using it in vertical split mode?

Change the split view display setting to "vertical" explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/05/vertical-split-view-vstipedit0081.aspx).

Comment: sorry, it has been a very long time. 

Since if using two monitors, it might be better to have design on a separate monitor. But thanks for the vertical split mode. It should be enough

Comment: @Habibi glad it helped, same feelings for 2 monitors though.